# Unable to build wso2 kernel 4.0.6

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-esb

When i am trying to build the wso2 kernel4.0.6, Build failed due to the f0llowing error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-

5:attached (2-dist) on project wso2carbon-core: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: 

\distribution\kernel\4.0.0\..\..\..\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.0.0\target\Version.aar isn't a file. ->
```

Comment: Did you check whether you have got the Version.aar file in place?

Comment: I am not sure where to find Version.aar. I searched in distribution->kernel->4.0.0->\..\..\..\ here i am stuck.

Comment: Search in `\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.0.0\target\ ` . `core` directory should be in the same directory as `distribution`.

Comment: Inside core org.wso2.carbon.core directory not present.

Comment: wso2-carbon-kernel-4.0.6 this is my directory where the code for kernel is checked-out. wso2-carbon-kernel-4.0.6\core\org.wso2.carbon.core not present

Answer (score 0):

As the file `\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.0.0\target\Version.aar` that maven is looking for isn't present, your build is failing.

Comment: I checked out the code form this link https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/distribution/kernel/4.0.6/. core\org.wso2.carbon.core not present can you give a svn link from where i can get the correct code.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the code in https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/patch-releases/4.0.6/ location and build. Use that URL location if you haven't done so.

Comment: Once this is successfully built then build distribution/ directory inside. I checked this and kernel 4.0.6 builds fine.